# Как увидеть в реальном времени сколько времени прошло от старта до завершения обновления данных?

Tags: c#, winforms

При обновлении данных хотелось бы видеть сколько времени прошло от старта до завершения. И видеть в реальном времени. Как это можно сделать, таймер в отдельном потоке?

Comment: Вы не таймер запускайте в отдельном потоке, а обновление данных. В основном потоке фиксируйте время до и после.

Comment: Таймеру вообще поток не нужен.

Answer (score 2):

Для записи времени выполнения можно использовать класс `Stopwatch` из пространства имен `System.Diagnostics`

```
var s2 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
for (int i = 0; i < _max; i++)
{
    int count = CountFor(testArray);
}
s2.Stop();

Console.WriteLine((s2.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds * 1000000 / _max).ToString("0.00 ns"));
```